# Build script fails on windows, but not on linux or OSX

Tags: node.js, windows, bash, shell, cmd

I have the following script in my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "pretest": "mkdir -p build && node -e 'process.stdout.write(\"export var version = \\\"\" + require(\"./package.json\").version + \"\\\";\\n\");' > build/version.js && rollup -f umd -n d3_random -o build/d3-random.js -- index.js"
}
```

Which fails exclusively on Windows with the following error message:

```
> d3-random@0.2.1 pretest C:\Users\Pepe\Dropbox\workspace\d3-random
> mkdir -p build && node -e 'process.stdout.write("export var version = \"" + require("./package.json").version + "\";\n");' > build/version.js && rollup -f umd -n d3_random -o build/d3-random.js -- index.js

[eval]:1
'process.stdout.write(export var version = "
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
at Object.<anonymous> ([eval]-wrapper:6:22)
at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
at node.js:587:27
at doNTCallback0 (node.js:428:9)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:357:13)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Anyone have any idea why this only fails on Windows and not on Unix based systems?

Additional information:

- **OS**: Windows 8.1 and 10 (tested with git-bash, win-bash and cygwin)
- **NodeJS version**: 5.0.0
- **npm version**: 3.3.6

Comment: It would seem the `'` which is supposed to be a quote processed by the shell somehow ends up being executed by `node`. Welcome to escape character hell - on Windows!

Comment: Incidentally, if the call to `mkdir` is invoking the Windows build-in mkdir command, the `-p` isn't valid.  (That command, run in a standard Windows shell, would create two folders, one of which is named `-p`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the code inside the `-e '...'` into a file, as inlining is problematic due to the embedded quotes. If the code is in a file, you free yourself from such issues, and the script will be more portable and easier to read.